# Count of XML nodes from response in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: xml, google-chrome-devtools

I got a response from an API and it is in XML format. My question is: 
How to get a number of XML nodes in response API using Chrome Developer Tools. I tried looking under Network and looked at the response API but didn't find any information on the node count.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$x("count(//*)")` in the console will count all the elements. If you want elements, text nodes, comments, and processing instructions, use `$x("count(//node())")`.

Comment: how do i get a count of parent nodes?

Comment: What do you define as a parent? An element that contains other elements? An element that contains text? An element that contains any other node() (text/element/comment/processing instruction)? To count elements that contain at least one other element, try `$x("count(//*[*])")`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure using the following in the console will count all the elements:

```
$x("count(//*)")
```

If you want elements, text nodes, comments, and processing instructions, use:

```
$x("count(//node())")
```

> how do i get a count of parent nodes?

What do you define as a parent? An element that contains other elements? An element that contains text? An element that contains any other node() (text/element/comment/processing instruction)?

To count elements that contain at least one other element, try:

```
$x("count(//*[*])")
```